# Ho to draw a cubic shape node and edge graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw the following in tikz (the colours and borders does not matter).
[image]

I can draw a simple rectangle as the following. May somebody please provide a hint how to extend this to the above version. (Or if there is already an online  template for the above cubic figure, that will be awesome if you can provide a link or add to the answers)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
    {
        C & D \\
        G & H \\};
    \path[-stealth]
    (m-2-1) edge  node [left] {10} (m-1-1)
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {4} (m-1-2)
    (m-2-2) edge  node [right] {12} (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1) edge  node [below] {7} (m-2-2);
    %(m-2-2) edge [dashed] node [below] {$M'_p$} (m-2-1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{90,143,222}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=scriptsize,
  column sep=scriptsize,
  cells={nodes={top color=myblue!50,bottom color=myblue,draw=myblue!70!black,text=white,rounded corners}},
  arrows={myblue,text=black,shorten >=1pt,shorten <= 1pt}
]
A\ar[rr,"1"]\ar[dr,"3"] & & B\ar[dr,"2"]\ar[<-,dd,"12",near end] & \\
& C\ar[rr,"4",near start,crossing over] & & D & \\
E\ar[rr,"5",near start]\ar[dr,"7"]\ar[uu,"9"] & & F\ar[dr,"6"] & \\
& G\ar[rr,"8"]\ar[uu,"10",crossing over,near start,swap] & & H\ar[uu,"11",swap] &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the colors, delete the `cells` and `arrows` keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=scriptsize,
  column sep=scriptsize,
]
A\ar[rr,"1"]\ar[dr,"3"] & & B\ar[dr,"2"]\ar[<-,dd,"12",near end] & \\
& C\ar[rr,"4",near start,crossing over] & & D & \\
E\ar[rr,"5",near start]\ar[dr,"7"]\ar[uu,"9"] & & F\ar[dr,"6"] & \\
& G\ar[rr,"8"]\ar[uu,"10",crossing over,near start,swap] & & H\ar[uu,"11",swap] &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a comment for those who want to substitute the node names  with math formula: you do not need to enclose them inside the dollar sign.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

[image: blue cube]

You can use `(x,y,z)` coordinates to specify the locations of the nodes in 3D. I've used a loop with 2 variables - the coordinate and the letter labelling it - to create named nodes at the corners of the cuboid. I then draw edges between these nodes, adding the labels using the shorthand syntax provided by the `quotes` library.

3 styles are used:

- `every edge quotes` is a standard style provided by the `quotes` library. This determines the format of the edge labels on the arrows.
- `blue block` defines the style for the nodes at the corners.
- `every edge` is a standard style determining the appearance of the edges used to draw the arrows.

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every edge quotes/.append style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily, midway, auto, inner sep=1pt},
    blue block/.style={top color=blue!50!gray!75, bottom color=blue!50!gray, font=\sffamily, text=white, rounded corners, outer sep=2.5pt},
    every edge/.append style={color=blue!50!gray, preaction={draw=white, ultra thick}, thick}
  ]
  \foreach \j/\i in {(-2,1,-1)/A,(0,1,-1)/B,(0,1,1)/C,(2,1,1)/D,(-2,-1,-1)/E,(0,-1,-1)/F,(0,-1,1)/G,(2,0-1,1)/H}
  \node [blue block] (\i) at \j {\i};
  \draw [->] (A) edge ["1"] (B) edge [<-, "9"] (E) edge ["3"] (C);
  \draw [->] (F) edge ["11"] (B) edge [<-, "5"] (E) edge ["6"] (H);
  \draw [->] (G) edge ["10"] (C) edge [<-, "8"] (E) edge ["7"] (H);
  \draw [<-] (D) edge ["2"] (B) edge ["4"] (C) edge ["12"] (H);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```