# Adding elements on the surfaces of a cubic diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Thanks to this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275049/ho-to-draw-a-cubic-shape-node-and-edge-graph-in-tikz); I can draw a nice cubic diagram as bellow:

[image]

with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[
        row sep=scriptsize,
        column sep=scriptsize,]
        A\ar[rr,"1",hook]\ar[dr,"2",hook] & & B\ar[dr,"3",hook]\ar[<-,dd,"10",near end] & \\
        & C\ar[rr,"4",near start,crossing over,hook] & & G & \\
        H\ar[rr,"5",near start,hook]\ar[dr,"6",hook]\ar[uu,"9"] & & D\ar[dr,"7", hook] & \\
        & E\ar[rr,"8",hook]\ar[uu,"11",crossing over,near start,swap] & & F\ar[uu,"12",swap] &
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to add an arrow or chevron (possibly on each of 6 sides of the cubic); for example, on the left surface I want to have something like:

[image]

I draw the above picture in powerpoint. Is it possible to achieve such a thing with latex? (the chevron shape in the picture is not a must; it can be replaced with double arrow or anything showing the purpose)

---

### Update:

I could manage to shift the chevron to the bellow surface according to the @Henri answer and his instructions below. Here it is:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[
  remember picture,
  row sep=scriptsize,
  column sep=scriptsize,]
  A\ar[rr,"1",hook]\ar[dr,"2",""{coordinate,name=two},hook] & & B\ar[dr,"3",hook]\ar[<-,dd,"10",near end] & \\
  & C\ar[rr,"4",near start,crossing over,hook] & & G & \\
  H\ar[rr,"5",near start,""{coordinate,name=five},hook]\ar[dr,"6",""{coordinate,name=six},hook]\ar[uu,"9",""{coordinate,name=nine}] & & D\ar[dr,"7",""{coordinate,name=seven}, hook] & \\
  & E\ar[rr,"8",""{coordinate,name=eight},hook]\ar[uu,"11",""{pos=.9,coordinate,name=eleven},crossing over,near end,swap] & & F\ar[uu,"12",swap] &
\end{tikzcd}



\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
conn/.style = {{Circle[scale=.5]}-{Stealth[scale=.5]},gray!40,
    shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1pt}
]
\node[draw,fill=red!20,signal,signal from=west,signal pointer angle=145,
inner sep=0pt,rotate=-28]
(PB) at ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=-1.46cm]\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2)
{\vrule height 2em width 0pt};
\node at ([yshift=15pt,xshift=15pt]PB.south) {\tiny PB};
\draw[conn] (five) to[bend right=10] (PB.80);
\draw[conn] (PB.280) to[bend left] (eight);
\draw[conn] (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-1) to[bend right=0] (PB);
\draw[conn] (PB) to[bend right=0] (\tikzcdmatrixname-4-4);
\draw[conn] (six) to[bend left=10] (PB.-70);
\draw[conn] (PB.80) to[bend right] (seven);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tikz-cd` diagram is just a usual `matrix of nodes`.  You can use the `remember picture` and `overlay` functionality to draw onto the existing drawing.

The positions where the arrows enter and emanate from the chevron are determined in a kind of hackish way, namely by trial and error.  Also, many dimensions are hardcoded, so scaling the drawing is not straight forward.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,cd,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  remember picture,
  row sep=scriptsize,
  column sep=scriptsize,]
  A\ar[rr,"1",hook]\ar[dr,"2",""{coordinate,name=two},hook] & & B\ar[dr,"3",hook]\ar[<-,dd,"10",near end] & \\
  & C\ar[rr,"4",near start,crossing over,hook] & & G & \\
  H\ar[rr,"5",near start,hook]\ar[dr,"6",""{coordinate,name=six},hook]\ar[uu,"9",""{coordinate,name=nine}] & & D\ar[dr,"7", hook] & \\
  & E\ar[rr,"8",hook]\ar[uu,"11",""{pos=.9,coordinate,name=eleven},crossing over,near start,swap] & & F\ar[uu,"12",swap] &
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
  conn/.style = {{Circle[scale=.5]}-{Stealth[scale=.5]},gray!40,
    shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1pt}
  ]
  \node[draw,fill=gray!40,signal,signal from=west,signal pointer angle=135,
  inner sep=0pt,rotate=220]
  (PB) at ([xshift=-.6cm,yshift=-.2cm]\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2)
  {\vrule height 2em width 0pt};
  \node at ([yshift=5pt]PB.south) {\tiny PB};
  \draw[conn] (two) to[bend left] (PB.246);
  \draw[conn] (PB.280) to[bend left] (nine);
  \draw[conn] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2) to[bend right=20] (PB);
  \draw[conn] (PB) to[bend right=20] (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-1);
  \draw[conn] (eleven) to[bend right] (PB.114);
  \draw[conn] (PB.80) to[bend right] (six);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Which parameters should I change to move  the chevron on the other surfaces? ( I tried some, but I failed) and Is it possible to skew it a little bit?

Comment: @qartal The chevron is placed `at ([xshift=-.6cm,yshift=-.2cm]\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2)`, i.e. 0.6 cm to the left and 0.2 cm below of “C”.  That is to say, you have to adjust `at (...)` of the `PB` node to place the chevron somewhere else.  You may rotate the chevron by changing `rotate=<angle>`, the skew parameter is `signal pointer angle`.

Comment: May you please take a look at the picture I added. How to shift the head of dotted arrows going from edge 6 to the chevron to touch the chevron edge.

Comment: @qartal Please post this as a new question.  [This is not a traditional forum.](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117)

Comment: I update the question. However, your post still remains answering the content in the question completely. I will post it as a question later if I can not figure that out.